# Trivial Cordova plugin not calling native function

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

Hey guys i'm trying to get a really simple custom cordova plugin to work, and it's not working and it's quite embarassing...

I've tried lookin at the phonegap tutorials for a [simple plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)  and how to [implement on android](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins), and it looks like I have the same thing but it ain't working! All it is supposed to do is call the native function with a string and eclipse outputs that string to the console log..., but the native function is never actually called!

**JAVA:**

```
public class ListPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, 
                      CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

       Log.d("CORDOVA", "!!!");
       if(action.equals("showString")){
            String message = args.getString(0);
            Log.d("CORDOVA", message + "!!!");
        }
       return true
    }

}
```

**RES/XML:**

```
<feature name="ListPlugin">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.flukenetworks.networkmap.ListPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("HERRO?");
    cordova.exec(null, null, "ListPlugin", "showString", ["I hate you"]);
</script>
```

Can anyone spot anything wrong? It's probably something really trivial that I can't see...I am getting a CordovaWebView Timeout error, maybe that has something to do with it? Here is the code with the CordovaWebView, for shits and giggles.

```
public class DevicesListFragment extends Fragment{

    CordovaWebView webView; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = new CordovaWebView(getActivity());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return webView;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I figured it out! The reason the native code isn't called, is that cordova isn't "ready" when I try and call `cordova.exec()`.

I solved this by adding an eventlistener:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "ListPlugin", "showString", ["I hate you"]);
}
```

In fact, Cordova/PhoneGap docs both recommend always using this - now I know!

Comment: In my case the cordova.exec call was not calling the my code as I did not use an array for the function arguments. I'm writing this in case somebody else gets here from a search engine. :)